# Randomly returning a alternate page in Nginx for A/B testing

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to return 20% of the time a different page in Nginx for a given URL and User-Agent header (for the purpose of A/B testing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the following module:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

It was created exactly for A/B testing.

Comment: Nice one, but is it built-in by default?

Comment: Yes, it is built-in as a [standard module](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules). See [wiki docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSplitClientsModule)

Comment: Yes, it builds by default. Here's the original documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

Answer (score 3):

With loadbalance feature,

```
http {
 upstream myproject {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=4;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
 }

 server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myproject;
  }
 }

 server {
  listen 8000;
  location / {
   root /var/www/A;
  }
 }

 server {
  listen 8001;
  location / {
   root /var/www/B;
  }
 }
}
```

Not so pretty, but maybe works :)

Comment: Interesting idea. How would you set up the proxies so that the A/B testing only affects some browsers (i.e. desktops vs mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

It can be use **split_clients** module with configuration

```
http {
  upstream myproject1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  }

  upstream myproject2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  }

  split_clients $remote_addr $upstream {
      25% myproject2;
      * myproject1;
  }


  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
  }

}
```